# REST шлюз Росфинмониторинга

Tags: c#, rest

Пытаюсь подключиться к этому сервису. Авторизацию прохожу, токен получаю.
Но на следующем шаге застрял - пытаюсь стучаться в /test-contur/suspect-catalogs/current-te2-catalog и /suspect-catalogs/current-te2-catalog, везде получаю 403.
Токен в хидер запихиваю, пытался и Authenticate, и Authorization писать, bearer с заглавной и прописной, без толку.
Возможно дело в том, что метод post, но что постить из инструкции, из тамошнего личного кабинета, непонятно.

В инструкции (справке) написано только  -

> Для доступа к другим методам сервиса необходимо поместить в
> http-запрос заголовок Authorization и указать в нём тип токена
> (bearer) доступа и токен доступа через пробел. Метод сервиса:
> test-contur/suspect-catalogs/current-te2-catalog Метод http запроса:
> POST

Я пытаюсь стучаться так (закомментированы варианты которые я тоже пробовал):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var person = new Person(userName, password);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
//string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("");
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + access_token);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authenticate", "Bearer " + access_token);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authenticate", "Bearer " + access_token);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", access_token);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
return await client.PostAsync(Url, httpContent);
```

Comment: Не думаю, что на ваш вопрос возможно дать ответ. Все API разные, имеют разную структуру, требования, и так далее. Ну а так, как документацию вы нам, как я понял, скинуть не можете, то и знать как работать с конкретным API мы не можем. Пишите в тех. поддержку, узнавайте что не так, раз делаете все по документации, но получаете "не авторизован". Также советую для начала использовать Postman или его аналоги, в котором вы без кода можете проверить нужный API, а затем это все, через простой `HttpClient` перенести в C#.

Comment: В справке должно быть указано как должен выглядеть заголовок и что в нем должно быть

Comment: Я немного изменил вопрос, в тексте есть все что что есть в их инструкции. Обращаться в их тех. поддержку не особо полезно, суда по тому, что народ пишет в и-нете, они всех отправляют инструкцию читать.

Comment: Токен значит неверный, ещё он в base64 должен быть

Comment: Токен верный. Не верно - "application/json". Методом перебора удалось подобрать правильное значение. Удалось получить ID файлов для скачивания. Но на этом снова застрял, по инструкции его нужно передавать соответствующим методам сервиса POSTом,  но в ответ стабильно теперь получаю 500. Возможно нужно еще что-то передавать, но в инструкции про это ничего нет.